# monaco editor react automcomplete is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, autocomplete, monaco-editor

I have a file called tf.d.ts with all the definitions in typescript, i want to add it as autocomplete material to the monaco editor. No matter what i try it still won't work. The autocomplete doesn't work.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Editor from "@monaco-editor/react";
import * as me from "monaco-editor"

function TensorFlowEditor({ tfjsLib }) {
  const editorRef = useRef(null);

  async function handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
    editorRef.current = editor;
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
      noSemanticValidation: true,
      noSyntaxValidation: false,
    });

    // compiler options
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
      target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
      allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    });
    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(tfjsLib, "ts:filename/tfjs.d.ts");
    console.log(monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib.toString())
  }

  function runCode() {
    const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
    console.log(eval(editorRef.current.getValue()))

  }
  let defaultCode = `
  
// Define a model for linear regression.
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

// Generate some synthetic data for training.
const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([1, 3, 5, 7], [4, 1]);

// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 10}).then(() => {
  // Use the model to do inference on a data point the model hasn't seen before:
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([5], [1, 1])).print();
  // Open the browser devtools to see the output
});

  `
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={runCode}>Run Code</button>
      <Editor
        height="90vh"
        defaultLanguage="javascript"
        defaultValue={defaultCode}
        theme="vs-dark"
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
      />
    </>
  );
}
export default TensorFlowEditor

export async function getStaticProps() {
  var fs = require("fs")
  var path = require("path")
  const currentDir = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public');
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(currentDir + '/tf.d.ts', 'utf8');
  return {
    props: {
      tfjsLib: fileContents
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the autocomplete to work. I tried to change to typescriptDefault, i tried to change languages between typescript and javascript, i tried without the last path paramenter. The file is read correctly, i checked with console.log, i tried using the tag useLib=false, true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue. I'm not 100% sure why this isn't working as the documentation says, but instead of using the `addExtraLib` method, using the `createModel` method worked for me.

```js
monaco.editor.createModel(`declare const myname: () => "garrett"`, 'typescript', monaco.Uri.parse('./types.d.ts'))
```

Using this method, I was able to get Intellisense to register my types and offer auto completion. I had discovered that when viewing the file in Monaco, then the types would work so I went down the path of initializing the editor with the `types.d.ts` file as the default path and then switching to my main file. This felt really hacky though.

I should also mention that I am using https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor

Another potential helpful thing for anyone who comes across this. In my situation, I am working on getting global types to work with Jest/test file and Monaco, and I was able to get auto completion and suggestions working after using the `createModal` method after mount. React example below.

```
import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react'

const MyEditor = () => {

  const handleEditorWillMount = (editor, monaco: Monaco) => {
    monaco?.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setEagerModelSync(true)

    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
      noSemanticValidation: true,
      noSyntaxValidation: false,
    })

    monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
      target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES2016,
      allowNonTsExtensions: true,
      allowJs: true,
      moduleResolution: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
      module: monaco.languages.typescript.ModuleKind.ESNext
    })

    // THIS IS WHAT GOT AUTO COMPLETION WORKING FOR ME
    // In my actual file, I replace the first argument with the `@types/jest` declaration file
    monaco.editor.createModel('declare const myname: () => "garrett"', 'typescript', monaco.Uri.parse('./types.d.ts'))
  }

  return (
   <Editor
     defaultLanguage="typescript"
     defaultValue={file}
     onChange={(value) => handleFileInput(fileName, value ?? '')}
     path={fileName}
     theme="vs-dark"
     options={{
       minimap: {
         enabled: false,
       },
     }}
     className="h-100"
     onMount={handleEditorWillMount}/>
  )
}
```